# Python/openpyxl: How can I use a for loop to iterate over a list of table names to create new excel tables?

Tags: python, for-loop, openpyxl, python-3.10

I am trying to create multiple tables in excel using for loops and openpyxl. In the below code, my for loop does not seem to be iterating over the totalTables list, as I am receiving this error at the end of the code:

ValueError: Table with name TotalChickensTable already exists

Can someone please help me understand why the for loop is not iterating to also create a table with displayname=TotalCOWSTable?

```
chickensTotal = Report_workbook['Total  - Chickens']
cowsTotal = Report_workbook['Total  - COWS']
totalSheets = [chickensTotal, cowsTotal]
totalChickensTable = 'TotalChickensTable'
totalCOWSTable = 'TotalCOWSTable'
totalTableList = [totalChickensTable, totalCOWSTable]

for sheet in totalSheets:
    for totalTables in totalTableList:
        tableParameters = Table(displayName=totalTables, ref="A7:" + get_column_letter(sheet.max_column) +
                                                str(sheet.max_row))

        style = TableStyleInfo(name="TableStyleMedium16", showFirstColumn=False,
                               showLastColumn=False, showRowStripes=True, showColumnStripes=False)

        tableParameters.tableStyleInfo = style
        sheet.add_table(tableParameters)
```

I tried to set my table name list as a list of strings at first, but that yielded the same error code.

Comment: Table names must be unique within a whole workbook. You code will create the same tables in two different worksheets.

Comment: @CharlieClark, thank you for the response! I am still struggling on this one, what would need to change about the above to create the second table in the second worksheet?